# Connection not stablished to LDAP Directory from Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript, ldap, acrobat

I'm trying to code a connection from an Adobe Acrobat document created with XI Pro to an LDAP directory storing employee basic info. However I'm not able to initiate the connection.

The Acrobat Javascript code I'm trying is as follows:

```
var oParams = { dirStdEntryID: "dir0",
dirStdEntryName: "Employee LDAP Directory",
dirStdEntryPrefDirHandlerID: "Adobe.PPKMS.ADSI",
dirStdEntryDirType: "LDAP",
server: "some.server.somewhere",
port: someport,
searchBase : "O=some,dc=dns,dc=add,dc=ress"
};
var sh = security.getHandler("Adobe.PPKMS");
var dirList = sh.directories;
var dirConnection = dirList[4].connect(oParams);
```

However all the the return I get is:

GeneralError: Operation failed.
Directory.connect:11:Console undefined:Exec
Connection could not be established. Check your directory configuration settings.

Couple of considerations:
   - server, port and searchbase are correct, as they work on similar code in VBScript.
   - dirList contains several different directories of different natures, the LDAP one I need to connect to is 4.

Comment: Where is this script being executed from? The DirConnection object is available only for batch, console and application level scripts. You won't be able to execute it from a button unless you create a trusted function for it first.

Comment: Script is executed from Console for development purposes, final operational version would be part of a Certified PDF which also accepts the DirConnection object..

Comment: For debugging purposes, add the line "console.println(dirList.toSource())" before the last line and see what it spits out.

Comment: @joelgeraci dirList.toSource() by itself just returns :
"NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method".
However dirList[4].toSource() gives back:
"({info:{dirStdEntryDirType:"LDAP", dirStdEntryID:"dir0", dirStdEntryName:"Employee LDAP Directory", dirStdEntryPrefDirHandlerID:"Adobe.PPKMS.ADSI", port:someport, searchBase:"O=some,dc=dns,dc=add,dc=ress", server:"some.server.somewhere"}, toString:function toString() {[native code]}, valueOf:function valueOf() {[native code]}, connect:function connect() {[native code]}})"

Comment: Take a look at the section on trusted functions in the documentation. That should get you around the NotAllowedError and let you use the function.